# Ace Editor (1.4.3) breaking line on wrong column when pressing [enter]

Tags: ace-editor

Unsure if I am doing something wrong or if Ace has a bug.  Is there a common mistake I could be making that would lead to this behavior?  Ace is reacting like the cursor is behind its actual position when reacting to the press of the enter key.

Just before enter is pressed:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL1vV.jpg

Just after enter is pressed:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YT8Bg.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by a css entry `white-space:nowrap;` I had added being applied to the editor.